# Can I send request body (Large JSON) in Jenkins remote API Call?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jobs

I want to remotely trigger a Job that triggers POST request to an API.

I need all data (body, url, auth, etc) through input jenkins request.

Is this possible? I found this [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) but this doesn't seem to work.

I tried the following URLs to trigger my job :
curl --request POST --header 'Authorization: Basic (auth)' --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"REQUEST_URL", "value":(url)},{"name":"REQUEST_BODY", "value":(json as string)}]}' (jenkinsUrl)/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec&token=(token)

response : --data-urlencode: command not found

curl --request POST --header 'Authorization: Basic (auth)' --data json='{"parameter": [{"name":"REQUEST_URL", "value":(url)},{"name":"REQUEST_BODY", "value":(json as string)}]}' (jenkinsUrl)/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec&token=(token)

response : nothing, job not triggered.

Note that the job gets triggered properly if I add all the params in the URL. My issue is that most of the request body will be too large to fit in request params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has beed resolved.

I used the following API call:

```
curl --request POST (jenkinsUrl)/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec&token=(token) --header 'Authorization: Basic (auth)' --data 'REQUEST_URL=(url)' --data 'REQUEST_BODY=(utf-8 encoded json as string)'
```

`REQUEST_URL` and `REQUEST_BODY` are parameters set in Jenkins Job that I'm building.